# Execute code in a github remote depot vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I use the vscode extension to modify code in a github depot but i would like to know if it is possible to execute the code without downloading it

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions) in your repository, which would [checkout your repository](https://github.com/actions/checkout), on demand, when you [trigger it manually](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow).

That same GitHub Action ca, execute any command you want inside the checked out repository (on Azure server: no need to download the code).

The [GitHub Actions for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschleiden.vscode-github-actions) could be used to trigger that same workflow directly from your VSCode, but might imply a clone first.